# Get active user control name from main window in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am working on to WPF with MVVM pattern and created multiple user control and load it on main window as per need. only one user control is to be loaded on main window at a time.

I want to get the name of active user control from main window.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Win.UI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="MainWindowForm" Title="Sample App" WindowState="Maximized" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" Closed="Window_Closed" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"        >
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="contentgrid" Panel.ZIndex="1" >
         //Load user controls dynamically as per need 
         // 1 user control is to be load at a time
         // i want to skip background worker on some user control thats why i want to get the active user control name
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What have you tied so far. Show your code.

Comment: If you are using the MVVM pattern then learning a little more about binding will probably answer your question in full. Your question is unclear why you need to get the name of the current UserControl. Typically the MainViewModel will contain a few instances of other ViewModels that you would set as needed to a property in the MainViewModel. You'd then bind the content of a UserControl to that property and use a Template to display what it should look like.

Comment: Basically i am using one background worker and it is running every 1 minutes. I wan to skip the background worker method on some user controls

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Content
```

This will give you the active content. If your user control is wrapped with any containers, you may need to iterate the visual tree and get it.

Comment: The OP mentioned using the MVVM pattern, and if his solution is setup to have a separate project for ViewModels (with no dependencies on any of WPF assemblies) then this solution will not work.